# Custom UITableViewCell shadow appears after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, quartz-core

I'm making an app in iOS6 using a custom table view cell in a table view controller. The cell has been designed using the prototype cell in storyboard.

In the table view controller I'm doing three things:

1. adding a simple custom animation to the cell in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
2. adding a rounded corner effect to the cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
3. adding a shadow effect to the cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

The problem is that when the table view is loaded, the 3 cells which initially appear are presented with the animation and rounded corners correctly but **without the shadow effect**. However, as I scroll down, the new cells which appear have the animation + rounded corners + shadow as well.

And, now when I scroll back up the initial 3 cells also have the shadow effect.

A few hours debugging this have left me all the more clueless. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem. [cell layoutSubviews] does everything I need:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    [cell layoutSubviews];
}

cell.imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
cell.imageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.imageView.bounds cornerRadius:5.0f].CGPath;
cell.imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.5f, 2.5f);
cell.imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.5f;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem:

Inside your `UITableViewCell` subclass, override `layoutSubviews` and then insert your code that adds the shadow. Finally make sure `super.layoutSubviews()` is called as the last line of code.

```
    override func layoutSubviews() 

    configureShadow() // <-- insert shadow code here, or create a method
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Then inside your view controller implement the `willDisplayCell` delegate method, cast the cell as your cell subclass, and on the main thread call `cell.layoutSubviews`

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let _cell = cell as! CustomCell // Replace CustomCell with your cell subclass 

         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            _cell.layoutSubviews()
        }
}
```